# What is meaning of 'head-rig' in nineteenth century English?

Tags: word-meaning

Manuscript written in late nineteenth century Ireland uses the term in conjunction with transportation or travel by road.  Does it refer to the conveyance or to the type of track over which the travel is undertaken?

Comment: Please provide the full context. A paragraph would be ideal.

Comment: Also, you'd find more interest in this question here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: There's an agricultural definition here, but not necessarily the one that will fit your context: https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=y_s3AQAAIAAJ&rdid=book-y_s3AQAAIAAJ&rdot=1  The strip of land at the end of a furrow where the farmer turns his team pulling the plow.  **head rig/head ridge**

Answer (score 1):

> [headrig - is Scottish for a headland in a ploughed field](https://books.google.com/books?id=pz2ORay2HWoC&pg=PA740&lpg=PA740&dq=horse+bridles+headrig&source=bl&ots=FGbYudc0_-&sig=yDrGqTUMZVC2Um0ULRAxAPhT31E&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZr4-joebRAhUN32MKHWQyDLIQ6AEILTAD#v=onepage&q=horse%20bridles%20headrig&f=false)

Comment: ***At** the headrig* doesn't refer to harness but to the turning ground at the end of the furrow which @TRomano cites.

Comment: Then I don't understand the explanation in the left side column for "headrig", unless the term is being used for both.

Comment: This is a student 'essay'; there's a couple more such minor mistakes.